# Insert Mulitple rows in a OUT parameter in a User-defined Table type HANA

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, procedure, hana

I am stuck at a place.

There is a procedure that checks for something and inserts into an table type upon successful determination of that condition.

But I can insert only once in the table type. Is there a way to insert again and again into the table type?

```
    PROCEDURE "hello"."helloWorld.db::sampleException" (OUT TRACE_RECORD "hello"."LogTrace" )
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE i int;

select count(*) into i from "hello"."REGION";
IF :i > 1 then 
TRACE_RECORD = SELECT '1' AS "LogID", '1' AS "TraceID" FROM DUMMY;
 end if;
IF :i > 2 then 
TRACE_RECORD = SELECT '2' AS "LogID", '2' AS "TraceID" FROM DUMMY;
end if;

END;
```

What I get on executing the procedure is only the last record "2,2".

How can I insert both the records 1,1 and 2,2?

Note: I do not want to use Temporary Tables.

Any help on this..

Thanks.!

Editing the question a bit:

- I have to use Table TYPE (till the time there is no optimal way better than it)
- I have to insert more than 20-30 records in the table type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to write this as a procedure? A table-valued function seems more suitable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_tables4 (in_id INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE (
    "LogID" VARCHAR(400),
    "TraceID" VARCHAR(400)
)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    SELECT t."LogID", t."TraceID"
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS i, '1' AS "LogID", '1' AS "TraceID" FROM DUMMY
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS i, '2' AS "LogID", '2' AS "TraceID" FROM DUMMY
    ) t
    JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM "hello"."REGION") c
    ON c.cnt > t.i
END
```

Comment: What if i have multiple conditions throughout the procedure. The above is just an example. I think this would not serve the purpose. @Lukas

Comment: @abhi5800: I don't know HANA's features well enough. In Oracle, you'd write a `PIPELINED` function. In SQL Server, you'd use an in-memory table and insert records there. But you can get quite far with SQL only. I'll leave the answer as it is, because for the question at hand, I think it's a reasonable answer. If you want to update your question with more specifics about why this won't work for you, I might adapt the answer

Comment: Thanks @Lukar.! The solution works for small data( as my question). But i was looking for a more optimal solution since i have to insert a number of rows in the Table type.

Comment: @abhi5800: It also works for 30 records - I'm not quite sure what the issue is so far. Style? SQL is not a bad thing, you know :-) certainly not necessarily worse than any equivalent procedural solution. If you can re-phrase your question to make it very clear why this solution is unsuitable for you (apart from stylistic concerns), then I'll reconsider, but as it stands now, this seems to be your best choice.

Comment: Thanks Lukas! It worked for 20+ records as of now. Probably going with the same solution. HANA ;)